# Formula to find login time and logout of employees

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of dates and times for employees with different card numbers who have entered and left the office. In Excel I need to find the first login time and last logout time for each date for reach employee. Also to calculate the duration in office. I have a big Excel sheet with 100 employees with a total  of 40k entries.

In the below picture, I need only the first login time and last logout time of card `6350` for date `Oct-1-2015`.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts Thank You, i shall share the data which can be copied in 3hrs.

Comment: @pnuts in the example, i have shown only one card number. However we have multiple cards numbers. 6351 for 2nd employee, 6352 for 3rd employee. U are correct in saying, i only need the first and last time for each date, with total hours spent in office (19:50 subtract with 11:45) to get total works hours.

Comment: @pnuts yes, i put the card numbers in row and date n time below it, however i was not able to remove the multiple Time between first In n Last out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on this formula: It works to me. Use the formula as array. Press `Ctrl`+ `Shift`+`Enter` after finishing typing formula

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$6=E$2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2,$A$2:$A$6)),$A$2:$A$6)))
=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$6=E$2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2,$A$2:$A$6)),$A$2:$A$6)))
```

[image]

Comment: Then apply format `HH:MM:SS AM/PM` to show only time. Or your preferred format.